# How to run ant build through jenkins at scheduled times?

Tags: java, selenium, ant, jenkins

I have created some test cases and placed them in `testng.xml` file. I have created a `build.xml`(ant build) file which is running without any errors. now my task is that i need to run all my test cases through `jenkins` integration tool using ant build.
I have installed jenkins on my ubuntu system.
what are the further configurations like creating a job, scheduling tasks ???

Comment: To start, if you're new to Java, don't use Ant; it's obsolete. Instead, use Maven or Gradle (each has their pros and cons; I use Maven). You can create a Jenkins job and tell it to run at scheduled intervals; I suggest reading a Jenkins tutorial for these basics.

Comment: Are you able to perform the tests manually in Jenkins?

Answer (score -1):

The next step is to create a job. Then set the workspace of that job ( usually your project directory), set the scheduler to run whenever you want. For the syntax of the scheduler (chronos) you have a help button.

For example:

`@midnight` will run every midnight

`* H/2 * * *` will run every 2 hours.

After that set the build command and save. You're done! Try a manual build by pressing on "build now" to see if you have configuration mistakes, if you have correct them and done.